# How to show cmd line output data in modal view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have a Laravel 5.2 admin page that has a sync button. It calls `php artisan sync` command that runs for around 10 minutes.

During it's run it echoes out multiple data lines like:

```
[1] Product name. Progress 100%.
[2] Product two name. Progress 90%
...
```

This is nice, if I call the sync from console, but I want also to display the same date in the admin page in a a bootstrap like modal similar to this:

[image]

so that the moderator can see the exact progress I see, when I run the command directly from the console.

**Haw can I accomplish this?**

*EDIT*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this idea for "real-time" approach

- In your sync command, save each message you want to show on model to a text file. With a success signal line on complete process
- In your admin page. Do a ajax (with interval) to get content in that file. If it catch the success line -> stop interval and clear text file

Comment: Thank you, interesting enough, this is exactly what I ended up doing without seeing your comment. I created a file with json data `[ total, current, changed, message ]`, that I update when `changed = true` ( and set to false, once read ). Also `total` and `current` help me create a progress bar. See updated question.

Comment: It's look great. I'll apply this for future admin panel :)